# jquery append only appends in first element of list or shows error [object Object]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable `var $deleteEl = $('<a class="upload_delete" href="#">Delete</a>');` which is a delete link that need to be created next to each uploaded image.
html structure is next:

```
<ul id="thumb_galery">
    <li class="thumb">
        <img>
        <a class="upload_delete"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="thumb">
        <img>
        <a class="upload_delete"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

for every uploaded image, thumb with image is appended to thumb_galery

```
$(thumb_galery).append('<li id="thumb"><img src="img/success.jpg" alt="' + fileName + '"></li>');
```

i need to add delete link in the same `li` next to the image as provided in html structure.

If i append delete link like this

```
$(thumb).append($deleteEl);
```

it works great for first image uploaded, but for next images it only appends it to the first `li` with class thumb.

How can the delete link be appended in `li` for the next uploaded image?

The other solution i tried is to place a variable in the first append like this

```
$(thumb_galery).append('<li class="thumb"><img src="img/success.jpg" alt="' + fileName + '">' + $deleteEl + '</li>');
```

This creates the perfect html structure but instead of delete link it shows [object Object]

Comment: That's because you should use **unique** `id`s. Like they're supposed to be. I'm guessing `thumb` is "#thumb", which only selects the **first** element with the `id` "thumb".

Comment: Show your **actual** code instead of confusing fragments/explanations.

Comment: `$deleteEl` isn't a string, it's a (jQuery) object.

Comment: Try `$(thumb_galery).append($('<li id="thumb"><img src="img/success.jpg" alt="' + fileName + '"></li>').append($deleteEl));`

Comment: @Ian Thanks, this is perfect. This is what i wanted.

Comment: You're missing the # for the id's. Should be `$('#thumb_gallery').append`

Comment: @Dušan Sounds good. I added an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the elements a unique `id` or use a class. And try:

```
var item = $('<li id="thumbX" class="thumb"><img src="img/success.jpg" alt="' + fileName + '"></li>');
item.append($deleteEl)
$(thumb_galery).append(item);
```

Comment: Your first solution worked perfectly and i changed id="thumb" to class="thumb". Thanks again.

Comment: @Dušan This is the same as my first solution, I just split it up so that it was more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly append it like this, You should not have multiple elements with the same id.

http://jsfiddle.net/xq8f7/

```
var $deleteEl = $('<a>',{ 
    'class': "upload_delete",
    href: "#",
    text: "Delete"});
$('.thumb').append($deleteEl);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. @Ian provided me with perfect solution, and i am changing id="thumb" to class="thumb" as you suggested so i will give you +1